# can't locate my file in subfolder nor read it (applescript)

Tags: applescript, text-files, posix, containers

I want to read text in a list from a textfile "test.txt" that's located in a subfolder called "data". The text is formatted as plain text, every line ends with enter. After all I want to work around that my code could not be saved anymore because I stored too many data like set names to {"Adam", "Adele",... which pumped the sctp over 500kb, by reading huge lists from textfiles.

Which way I try, I end up getting the xyz.app-name in my set folder, I don't know how its better to use read or do it with POSIX, or I get permission trouble when I use container of to filter my filename, nor where to nest the code to open the file.

Can someone help me start?

EDIT

I tried a bit and got a solution that worked for me, reading my text in a list. See below.
Then I came to another problem: One list I could not save in MacOSRoman, so I had to use Unicode UTF-16. But I can't break myfile2 into a list anymore. Can someone help me out with this?

As a new user I could not upload my screenshot, so here is the code:
set List1 to (read file myFile1 using delimiters linefeed) as list
set List2 to (read file myFile2 using delimiters linefeed as Unicode text) as list

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these:

```
set aData to read file "Mac OS X:Users:j0k:Desktop:text file.txt"
set bData to read POSIX file "/Users/j0k/Desktop/text file.txt"
set cData to read alias "Mac OS X:Users:j0k:Desktop:text file.txt"
set dData to do shell script "cat '/Users/j0k/Desktop/text file.txt'"
```

An easy way of getting the path to your file is to drag the file into the script editor.

EDIT:

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFolder to container of (path to me) as text
set myFile to myFolder & "Data:test.txt"
set aData to read file myFile
```

[image]

Comment: I dont know where people will unpack the folder structure, so the subfolder-call must be variablel to the run-folder.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear to me. Where is the text file located? Maybe revise your question to step 1 step 2 etc.

Comment: My programms location is where you unpack it, like xyz:yourfavouritefolder:yourchoice:Program, and the subfolder is xyz:yourfavouritefolder:yourchoice:Program:Data

Comment: After you save your program in the folder, the Edited version should get you to the test.txt file

Comment: Thanks alot! I tried a bit and got a solution that worked for me, reading my text in a list. See below. Then i came to another problem: One list I could not save in MacOSRoman, so I had to use Unicode UTF-16. But I cant break myfile2 into a list anymore. Can someone help me out with this?

As a new user i could not upload my screenshot, so here is the code:
set List1 to (read file myFile1 using delimiters linefeed) as list
set List2 to (read file myFile2 using delimiters linefeed as Unicode text) as list